# Custom State Handling for Extended Apps

Tags: annotations, sapui5, cap

I have tried below blog but apply additional state method not trigerred and not retrurning saved addition information.

I have cap application backend in java .

https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#/topic/89fa878945294931b15a581a99043005

applyAdditionalStates method not getting trigered.